# How to consider a text value as a particular number in MS excel in SUM formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I apologize if the question is duplicate. I tried searching but I couldn't find it.

I have Column in Excel like:

```
a   | b   | c    | total
10  | 5   | 5    | 20
5   | -   | 2    | 7
4   | -   | -    | 4
```

I want to write a formula for `total` as sum `=SUM(a,b,c)`. But as `-` is not a number (excel treating it as subtract sign probably) it doesn't provide desired results. I need to somehow consider `NA` as `0` in `SUM`.

**Note:** I can not use `0` in place of `NA`. It is requirement to fill absent data as `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **D2** enter:

```
=SUM(A2:C2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

As you see from the illustration above the `SUM()` function treats the text value **-** as a zero when performing the sum in the **:** format.

**EDIT#1:**

To assign the numeric value of 15 to the **-** symbol, you could use:

```
=SUM(A2:C2)+15*COUNTIF(A2:C2,"-")
```

[image]

Extending this approach would allow you to assign different numeric values to different symbols and letters.

Comment: oh yes, I don't know what was going on earlier, It wasn't working earlier but it's working now :(. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, if I wanted to consider the `-` as any number, let's say `15`, how can we do that?

Comment: @CodeTalker  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thankyou so much @Gary's Student, that's all that I wanted to know. :)